# Finding all instances where a matchword is used in a csv file using python

Tags: python, excel, parsing, csv

I have a csv file that has numerous columns

here is an image of what the excel file looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB6TP.png

I need to look through the thousands of rows, in the column labeled Hit Definition for any virus with the name "grapevine" in it. 
For each word with the name "grapevine", I need to compile how many times it is mentioned, the range of length (column labeled query length, [2]), and the summation of reads(column total reads, [4]).

Input:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB6TP.png

output:

> Grapevine 1    6    234-234234 45634
>
> Grapevine 2    7    123-65432  12341

```
with open(argv[1], 'r') as f:
   for line in csv.reader(f):      
           contig_name = line[0]
           contig_length = line[3]
           read_count = line[4]
           hit_def = line[6]

           try:
                   pattern = r'.\[(.*?)\].'
                   hit_sub = re.search(pattern, hit_def).group(1)
                   print hit_sub

          except AttributeError:
                   hit_sub = hit_def


                   target.append([hit_sub])
```

this is what I have so far
I am lost on how to filter the names

Comment: Your pattern makes no sense for your problem, also sum and line.count("grapevine") might be sufficent

Answer (score 0):

Since you're lost on how to filter names, try:

```
re.findall("Grapevine",f)
```